# Why is the Gauge flickering on new value?

Tags: asp.net

Hi there I am using this Circular Gauge on my website:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGaugesDemos/Gauges/CircularGauge.aspx

http://neoizleme.com/ : my website

The Gauge disappears and comes again but on the demo website when you change a value it doesnt disappears says Loading and then comes the new version without flickering.

Do you know what might be causing this?How can I prevent the flickering and make it like on demo "Loading"

Answer (score 0):

The website is fetching the new image using Javascript and then replacing the image. This happens too fast for you to notice as the downloading happens in the background.

Your website is downloading the image in place as part of a partial postback.

Comment: Is there a way I can make it like on the demo website with Loading and the image not disappearing(flickering?)

Comment: The best way I can think of is to use Javascript to create a new img tag with the new guage in it, and then when that has finished loading swap it with the one that was there to begin with